# Slow SQL Server Query due to calculations?

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, timeout

I am responsible for an old time recording system which was written in ASP.net Web Forms using ADO.Net 2.0 for persistence.

Basically the system allows users to add details about a piece of work they are doing, the amount of hours they have been assigned to complete the work as well as the amount of hours they have spent on the work to date.

The system also has a reporting facility with the reports based on SQL queries. Recently I have noticed that many reports being run from the system have become very slow to execute. The database has around 11 tables, and it doesn’t store too much data. 27,000 records is the most records any one table holds, with the majority of tables well below even 1,500 records.

I don’t think the issue is therefore related to large volumes of data, I think it is more to do with poorly constructed sql queries and possibly even the same applying to the database design.

For example, there are queries similar to this

```
@start_date datetime, 
@end_date datetime,
@org_id int 

select distinct t1.timesheet_id, 
                t1.proposal_job_ref, 
                t1.work_date AS [Work Date], 
                consultant.consultant_fname + ' ' + consultant.consultant_lname AS [Person], 
                proposal.proposal_title AS [Work Title], 
                t1.timesheet_time AS [Hours],

--GET TOTAL DAYS ASSIGNED TO PROPOSAL
(select sum(proposal_time_assigned.days_assigned)-- * 8.0) 
from proposal_time_assigned
where proposal_time_assigned.proposal_ref_code = t1.proposal_job_ref ) 
as [Total Days Assigned],


--GET TOTAL DAYS SPENT ON THE PROPOSAL SINCE 1ST APRIL 2013 
(select isnull(sum(t2.timesheet_time / 8.0), '0') 
from timesheet_entries t2 
where t2.proposal_job_ref = t1.proposal_job_ref 
and t2.work_date <= t1.work_date 
and t2.work_date >= '01/04/2013' ) 
as [Days Spent Since 1st April 2013],

--GET TOTAL DAYS REMAINING ON THE PROPOSAL 
(select sum(proposal_time_assigned.days_assigned) 
from proposal_time_assigned 
where proposal_time_assigned.proposal_ref_code = t1.proposal_job_ref )
- 
(select sum(t2.timesheet_time / 8.0) 
from timesheet_entries t2 
where t2.proposal_job_ref = t1.proposal_job_ref 
and t2.work_date <= t1.work_date
 ) as [Total Days Remaining]

from timesheet_entries t1, 
consultant, 
proposal, 
proposal_time_assigned 

where (proposal_time_assigned.consultant_id = consultant.consultant_id)
     and (t1.proposal_job_ref = proposal.proposal_ref_code) 
     and (proposal_time_assigned.proposal_ref_code = t1.proposal_job_ref)
     and (t1.code_id = @org_id) and (t1.work_date >= @start_date) and (t1.work_date <= @end_date) 
    and (t1.proposal_job_ref <> '0')

order by 2, 3
```

Which are expected to return data for reports. I am not even sure if anyone can follow what is happening in the query above, but basically there are quite a few calculations happening, i.e., dividing, multiplying, substraction. I am guessing this is what is slowing down the sql queries.

I suppose my question is, can anyone even make enough sense of the query above to even suggest how to speed it up.

Also, should calculations like the ones mentioned above ever been carried out in an sql query? Or should the this be done within code?

Any help would be really appreciated with this one.

Thanks.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was discontinued with the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (more than **20 years** ago)

Comment: This is a good candidate to convert into a SQL Server Table-valued Function instead of one monolithic query...

Comment: Using the comma separated tables and where clause instead of joins will not have any affect on performance.

Comment: @marc_s - yes, but that is only style, the query optimizer should not be too negatively affected by that, although in some cases it could be.

Comment: @DavidFleeman: sure, it probably won't help much with performance, but it **sure** will help **readability** and being up to date with the current standards!

Comment: I agree with other comments about readability of query is also important. and the performance issue is not because of calculations but because each select column is written as correlated sub-query. having business calculation in code/db is not in the scope of this answer but i have seen lot more complex business logic in sql procs and yet it works fine. have you tried rewriting this query with JOIN   ? give it a try and lets us know your attempts/results. if you want to improve your skills as well or I will post answer soon.

Comment: Thanks for your comments folks. I've been attempting to rewrite my query using JOINS, however, it is taking me a while to get my head around the various types of JOINS. @AnupShah Did you get time to post your JOIN answer? Thanks again.

Comment: I have post the query with some assumptions and my best guess about relationships between tables. if you post more information about tables then sure we can complete remaining columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

based on the information given i had to do an educated guess about certain table relationships. if you post the table structures, indexes etc... we can complete remaining columns in to this query.

As of right now this query calculates "Days Assigned", "Days Spent" and "Days Remaining"
for the KEY "timesheet_id and proposal_job_ref"

what we have to see is how "work_date", "timesheet_time", "[Person]", "proposal_title"  is associate with that. 
are these calculation by person and Proposal_title as well ?

you can use [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) to provide us the sample data and output so we can work off the meaning full data instead doing guesses.

```
    SELECT 
             q1.timesheet_id
            ,q1.proposal_job_ref
            ,q1.[Total Days Assigned]
            ,q2.[Days Spent Since 1st April 2013]
            ,(
                q1.[Total Days Assigned] 
                - 
                q2.[Days Spent Since 1st April 2013]
            ) AS [Total Days Remaining]
    FROM
    (
        select 
            t1.timesheet_id
            ,t1.proposal_job_ref
            ,sum(t4.days_assigned) as [Total Days Assigned]
        from tbl1.timesheet_entries t1
        JOIN tbl1.proposal t2
            ON t1.proposal_job_ref=t2.proposal_ref_code
        JOIN tbl1.proposal_time_assigned t4
            ON t4.proposal_ref_code = t1.proposal_job_ref
        JOIN tbl1.consultant t3
            ON t3.consultant_id=t4.consultant_id
        WHERE t1.code_id = @org_id
            AND t1.work_date BETWEEN @start_date AND @end_date
            AND t1.proposal_job_ref <> '0'
        GROUP BY t1.timesheet_id,t1.proposal_job_ref
    )q1
    JOIN
    (
        select 
            tbl1.timesheet_id,tbl1.proposal_job_ref
            ,isnull(sum(tbl1.timesheet_time / 8.0), '0') AS [Days Spent Since 1st April 2013]
        from tbl1.timesheet_entries tbl1
        JOIN tbl1.timesheet_entries tbl2
            ON tbl1.proposal_job_ref=tbl2.proposal_job_ref
            AND tbl2.work_date <= tbl1.work_date
            AND tbl2.work_date >= '01/04/2013'
        WHERE tbl1.code_id = @org_id
            AND tbl1.work_date BETWEEN @start_date AND @end_date
            AND tbl1.proposal_job_ref <> '0'
        GROUP BY tbl1.timesheet_id,tbl1.proposal_job_ref
    )q2
        ON q1.timesheet_id=q2.timesheet_id 
        AND q1.proposal_job_ref=q2.proposal_job_ref
```

Comment: Thanks, this has been a great help.

Answer (score 1):

The Problem what i see in your query is :

1> Alias name is not provided for the Tables.
2> Subqueries are used (which are execution cost consuming) instead of WITH clause.

if i would write your query it will look like this :

```
select distinct t1.timesheet_id, 
                t1.proposal_job_ref, 
                t1.work_date AS [Work Date], 
                c1.consultant_fname + ' ' + c1.consultant_lname AS [Person], 
                p1.proposal_title AS [Work Title], 
                t1.timesheet_time AS [Hours],

--GET TOTAL DAYS ASSIGNED TO PROPOSAL
(select sum(pta2.days_assigned)-- * 8.0) 
from proposal_time_assigned pta2
where pta2.proposal_ref_code = t1.proposal_job_ref ) 
as [Total Days Assigned],


--GET TOTAL DAYS SPENT ON THE PROPOSAL SINCE 1ST APRIL 2013 
(select isnull(sum(t2.timesheet_time / 8.0), 0) 
from timesheet_entries t2 
where t2.proposal_job_ref = t1.proposal_job_ref 
and t2.work_date <= t1.work_date 
and t2.work_date >= '01/04/2013' ) 
as [Days Spent Since 1st April 2013],

--GET TOTAL DAYS REMAINING ON THE PROPOSAL 
(select sum(pta2.days_assigned) 
from proposal_time_assigned pta2
where pta2.proposal_ref_code = t1.proposal_job_ref )
- 
(select sum(t2.timesheet_time / 8.0) 
from timesheet_entries t2 
where t2.proposal_job_ref = t1.proposal_job_ref 
and t2.work_date <= t1.work_date
 ) as [Total Days Remaining]

from timesheet_entries t1, 
consultant c1, 
proposal p1, 
proposal_time_assigned pta1

where (pta1.consultant_id = c1.consultant_id)
     and (t1.proposal_job_ref = p1.proposal_ref_code) 
     and (pta1.proposal_ref_code = t1.proposal_job_ref)
     and (t1.code_id = @org_id) and (t1.work_date >= @start_date) and (t1.work_date <= @end_date) 
    and (t1.proposal_job_ref <> '0')

order by 2, 3
```

Check above query for any indexing option & number of records to be processed from each table.

Answer (score 1):

Check your databases for indexes on the following tables (if those columns are not indexed, then start by indexing each).

- proposal_time_assigned.proposal_ref_code
- proposal_time_assigned.consultant_id
- timesheet_entries.code_id
- timesheet_entries.proposal_job_ref
- timesheet_entries.work_date
- consultant.consultant_id
- proposal.proposal_ref_code

Without all of these indexes, nothing will improve this query.

The only thing in your query that would affect performance is the way you are filtering the [work_date].  Your current syntax causes a table scan:

```
--bad
and t2.work_date <= t1.work_date 
and t2.work_date >= '01/04/2013'
```

This syntax uses an index (if it exists) and would be much faster:

```
--better
and t2.work_date between t1.work_date and '01/04/2013'
```